# ERROR: Nil Can't be Coerced into a Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, sum

I have the following function to sum all the records of an `:amount` field in my `Pack` model for that given user:

**user.rb**

```
  def total_money_spent_cents
    amount = self.packs.map(&:amount).sum
    return amount
  end
```

However, when I use this function I receive the following error:

```
nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I am still having issues in regards to Fixnum in my tests, and have another question open [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061776/error-nil-cant-be-coerced-into-fixnum).

Comment: some of your packs must have an amount equal to nil, try `self.packs.map(&:amount).select {|x| x != nil}.sum`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This suggests that one of your packs has an amount field which has not yet been set, so is `nil`. When you try and add it to something else, it undergoes Type coercion, to see if Ruby can massage its type into one that can be added to numbers, but it can't, and so you have this error.

One solution is this:

```
def total_amount_spent_cents
  packs.map(&:amount).compact.sum
end
```

[`Array#compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-compact) removes the `nil` elements.

This may be fixing the symptom and not the actual problem though. It could be the case that you shouldn't have `nil`'s in there at all, in which case you should check the initialisation of your `Pack` model (or perhaps its validations, to ensure that `amount` is mandatory).

Comment: I was trying to remember what the function to remove nil values was, `compact`, thanks.

Comment: This is what I suspected, and compact does indeed remove the error, while also resulting in a correct calculation.

The strange thing is that my database only currently has a total of two Pack entries, both of which have a valid amount. The Pack model also validates the presence of an amount. Thank you for the solution - but I wonder where the nil value is coming from!

Comment: Potentially, if you used a method like `User.build_pack` or have your `inverse_of` relations set, then the User model will be aware of packs that exist in memory, but not in the database, and are associated to its ID. Then there can be packs associated to the user that have not been validated, and so could have nil values.

Answer (score 0):

I added some extra methods into Array and Hash for this sort of thing:  they're like `compact` but they remove all values returning true for `blank?` rather than just nil: so will remove empty strings, empty arrays, hashes etc.

```
class Hash    
  def compact_blank!
    self.each{|k,v| self.delete(k) if v.blank? }
    self
  end

  def compact_blank
    self.dup.compact_blank!
  end
end

class Array
  def compact_blank!
    self.delete_if(&:blank?)
  end

  def compact_blank
    self.dup.compact_blank!
  end  
end
```

use like

```
["1", "abc", "", nil, []].compact_blank
=> ["1", "abc"]
```

it's useful with params especially, where you might get a lot of empty strings through.